# Cannot add or draw non point features in Collector

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I've come across an issue with Collector. I'm in the process of developing editable online maps for a Biologist to collect field data, but I cannot add any features other than point features in the field. Adding the polygon or line features in AGOL's map viewer works fine, but I am unable to do this in Collector. Whenever I attempt adding one of these features, I get the red colored errors “No valid Length” (for lines) or “No valid Area” (for polygons) below the symbol. See the photos below. An example of my web map is here: http://arcg.is/14yDm1

I’m using an iOS iphone 5s and its updated. I’ll try asking ESRI at the conference if all else fails.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create them using GPS? What if you click the map symbol in your screenshots and digitilize manually?

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to add them using GPS, but I cannot add anything other than point features.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[post](https://community.esri.com/thread/160658)** from a user with a similar question on the Esri forums. Check those answers and see if they help. You may have gone down this road already, but here is a **[workflow](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ios/collect-data/draw-a-shape.htm)** for adding features as well as a **[troubleshooting guide](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ios/collect-data/troubleshoot-collect.htm#anchor3)**.